# Alternative to NOT IN()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with 14,028 rows from November 2012. I also have a table with 13,959 rows from March 2013. I am using a simple `NOT IN()` clause to see who has left:

```
select * from nov_2012 where id not in(select id from mar_2013)
```

This returned 396 rows and I never thought anything of it, until I went to analyze who left. When I pulled all the ids for the lost members and put them in a temp table (`##lost`), 32 of them were actually still in the `mar_2013` table. I can pull them up when I search for their ids using the following:

```
select * from mar_2013 where id in(select id from ##lost)
```

I can't figure out what is going on. I will mention that the `id` field I created is an `IDENTITY` column. Could that have any effect on the matching using `NOT IN`? Is there a better way to check for missing rows between tables? I have also tried:

```
select a.* from nov_2012 a left join mar_2013 b on b.id = a.id where b.id is NULL
```

And received the same results.

This is how I created the identity field;

```
create table id_lookup( dateofcusttable date ,sin int ,sex varchar(12) ,scid int identity(777000,1)) 
insert into id_lookup (sin, sex) select distinct sin, sex from [Client Raw].dbo.cust20130331 where sin <> 0 order by sin, sex
```

This is how I added the scid into the march table:

```
select scid, rowno as custrowno
into scid_20130331
from [Client Raw].dbo.cust20130331 cust
left join id_lookup scid
on scid.sin = cust.sin
and scid.sex = cust.sex

update scid_20130331
set scid = custrowno where scid is NULL --for members who don't have more than one id or sin information is not available

drop table Account_Part2_Current
select a.*, scid
into Account_Part2_Current
from Account_Part1_Current a
left join scid_20130331 b
on b.custrowno = a.rowno_custdmd_cust
```

I then group all the information by the scid

Comment: sorry this is not particularly well explained could you perhaps supply a small sample of you schema and some sample data and say what you are trying to acheive

Comment: The ID fields will not match the names behind them.  You may want to do the comparison on a different field.

Comment: Why are you using a *global* ##temp table instead of a local #temp table?

Comment: @Richard - I'm not sure what you mean by the ID fields will not match the names behind them. The original ID field was created using identity, then the same id was matched and more ids were created if  needed. I know the IDs match, I'm just not sure why SQL isn't pulling them up with the not in() statement.

Comment: @Aaron - I wasn't aware there was a difference between the ## and # temp tables. I will use # from now on. Changing it to a local table doesn't seem to affect my query results at all though

Comment: @Swizanson no, and I didn't suggest using local #temp tables to fix the problem, but rather to prevent other problems.

Comment: What are mar_2013 id and nov_2012 id types?

Comment: @Barabba - both are id(int, null)

Comment: @Swizanson - If these ID fields are both Identity fields, they could not possibly match.  How was the March table populated?

Comment: Also the `scid` column can't possibly be null. Does this return 0 or 1? `SELECT is_nullable FROM sys.columns
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.id_lookup') AND name = N'scid';`?

Answer (score 11):

I would prefer this form (and [here's why](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)):

```
SELECT a.id --, other columns 
  FROM dbo.nov_2012 AS a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.mar_2013 WHERE id = a.id);
```

However this should still give the same results as what you've tried, so I suspect there is something about the data model that you're not telling us - for example, is `mar_2013.id` nullable?

Comment: Yes, both fields are nullable, however, there are no null values in either table. Can I change this property on the field? Or do I have to make a new table?

Comment: @Swizanson it's an `IDENTITY` column in both tables? Can I ask why you have a different table for every month, and how you guarantee that the IDs match? The design seems questionable and non-scalable. Why not have a members table instead of trying to match these IDs?

Comment: We have members with multiple ids, so I created a roll-up process using distinct SIN and an identity field. I add new sins each month, but the ID field stays the same for previous members. I then group by the groupid (which is the ID I'm talking about now) to get the combined information for each member. It's stored as an (int,null) in both tables now, but it started as an identity field originally.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like horrendously overworked and wasteful design. Why do members have multiple ids? Also can you show the syntax you used to create a nullable IDENTITY column?

Comment: It absolutely is a horrendous way to do what we're doing, however, we get our data directly from clients and have no control over how it is entered (right now, if someone goes to a location and forgets their card/can't remember what phone # it's stored under, they get a new id). We are in the process of investing in some fuzzy logic matching software, but as a small start up company, we aren't quite there yet. This is how I created the original table;

Comment: Oh please don't add CREATE TABLE syntax in a comment, update the question.

Comment: How can an identify field ever be null?

Comment: @Richard that's why I asked for the syntax. When I posted my answer I hadn't noticed that it was an identity column, and the OP insists it is nullable, which is why I then asked for syntax.

Comment: I think the null issue might be when I'm joining it back to the customer table for roll-up. I create an int field and insert the value into the int field based on the sin/gender match.

Answer (score 1):

this is logically equivalent to not in and is faster than not in.

```
where yourfield in
(select afield
from somewhere
minus
select
thesamefield
where you want to exclude the record
)
```

It probably isn't as fast as using where not exists, as per Aaron's answer so you should only use it if not exists does not provide the results you want.

Comment: SQL users can replace that MINUS with EXCEPT, which is similar, but also includes a DISTINCT action in the results.